# Как задать значение для LocalTime.now()?

Tags: java, время, java-8

Тестирую сервис при помощи `JUnit 5` и `Spring Test`. В сервисе есть проверка: перед выполнением действия вытаскивается `LocalTime.now()` и проверяется, что сейчас меньше **11:00**, в противном случае выбрасывается ошибка.

Сейчас на часах **22:42**. А значит тесты будут валиться, пока я не дождусь полночи. Времени у меня не так много, поэтому хочу узнать: есть ли возможность задать определённое значение времени, чтобы оно возвращалось при вызове `LocalTime.now()`?

Я могу использовать класс `Clock`, но что мне с ним делать? Я же не смогу подменить часы в сервисе, а он будет обращаться к стандартным часам.

Comment: Поменяйте системное время

Comment: @КириллМалышев разумеется можно, но мне кажется, что это плохой подход. Неужели я единственный, кто сталкивается с такой проблемой? Неужели нет никаких инструментов для тестирования со временем?

Comment: Можно получать время не внутри проверяющего метода, а передавать его снаружи. В тесте задаете нужное время (например, как `LocalTime.of(10, 59, 59)`), и передаете его в метод. Метод в зависимости от переданного времени падает или нет.

Comment: @insolor да можно... Но логика такая, что сервис сам получает время при помощи LocalTime.now(). Не хотелось бы эту логику менять.

Comment: Ну так вам нужно протестировать не то, как сервис получает время от системы, а как сервис реагирует на разное время. Вот и вынесите проверяющий метод отдельно, и его и тестируйте.

Comment: А про Mockito сльішали? Тупо замокать и все!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил довольно просто, без изысков.
Вынес получение времени из сервиса в отдельный утильный класс:

```
public class VoteUtil {
    private static LocalTime endVoteTime = LocalTime.of(11, 0);

    private VoteUtil() {
    }

    public static boolean isCanReVote() {
        return LocalTime.now().isBefore(endVoteTime);
    }

    public static void prepareEndVoteTimeForPassTests() {
        if (LocalTime.now().getHour() >= endVoteTime.getHour()) {
            endVoteTime = LocalTime.of(23, 59);
        }
    }

    public static void prepareEndVoteTimeForFailTests() {
        if (LocalTime.now().getHour() < endVoteTime.getHour()) {
            endVoteTime = LocalTime.of(0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Последние два метода - продвинутые сеттеры. Первый выставляет время так, чтобы тесты проходили, а второй - чтобы падали.

Comment: выглядит отвратительно =( Вам надо инстанцировать LocalDate на основе Clock, который вы передаете в свой сервис, через метод LocalDate.now(clock). Поэтому в тестах вам надо создать кастомный clock (можно через метод Clock.fixed), а в основном коде использовать Clock.systemDefaultZone()

Comment: @AndrewBystrov не могу уловить разницу... А какие изъяны будут отсутствовать в вашем варианте в сравнении с моим?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov и в тестах сервисов ладно... А как мне передавать Clock в тестах контроллеров?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov  Я могу сделать отдельный конфиг для тестов, в котором будет подаваться мой фиктивный Clock. Но дело в том, что тесты проводятся одновременно на то, что сейчас время меньше дедлайна и больше дедлайна. А конфиг на оба теста будет один и тот же